# Using C#, .NET Core 3 and GTK# for cross-platform Programming (and alternatives)

Tags: c#, .net-core, mono, cross-platform, gtk#

I am about to start development of a software project that should run on Linux and Windows if possible. As I already have some experience with C# I am eager to use it for this project. I assumed that with .NET Core 3 and GTK# 3.22 this shouldn't be a problem since .NET Core App should be cross-platform out of the box. GTK# - from my understanding - should work everywhere GTK+ in the same version is also available.

Why c#? Well I just like the language and there is an ECS Framework for c# I'd like to use.

So far I have setup a test Console App project in Visual Studio targeting .NET Core 3 and added an [GTK# specific NuGet package](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp).

I wrote a simple Hello World program for testing of the environment.

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace GTKTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();
            Window win = new Window("Hello GTK");
            Label lbl = new Label("This is a test GTK App written with C# for GNU/Linux and Windows");
            win.DeleteEvent += Win_DeleteEvent;
            win.Add(lbl);
            win.ShowAll();
            Application.Run();
            win.Dispose();
            Console.Write("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Win_DeleteEvent(object o, DeleteEventArgs args)
        {
            Application.Quit();
            args.RetVal = true;
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this code from Visual Studio 2019 I get

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Gtk.Application' threw an exception.
  Source=GtkSharp
  StackTrace:
   at Gtk.Application.Init()
   at GTKTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Workspace\VSRepos\C#\GTKTest\Program.cs:line 10

Inner Exception 1:
DllNotFoundException: Gtk
```

While searching for a solution I installed mono and [GTK# for Windows from this page](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-win). The mono part shouldn't be necessary if I stick to .NET Core I think.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong? Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible like I am imaging it? I'm also interested in some alternatives how to program cross-platform GUI-Software with C#. I stumbled upon electron.js but I heard it has some big Memory overhead and I'm not really into javascript. AvaloniaUI sounded interesting but I thought that the above approach would be better.

Edit: After adding msys path like suggested [here in step 3](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/wiki/Installing-Gtk-on-Windows) I get following error preceding the exception from above. The error states that the procedure entry point couldn't be found in the dll.

[image]

Comment: The error message is telling you it didn't find the Gtk dll, so its missing. Did you follow [step 3](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/wiki/Installing-Gtk-on-Windows) of the Gtk Installation guidelines? Also here are some alternatives: [Electron.NET](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET) at least the backend is C#, [Electron.NET with Blazor frontend](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ElectronNET.Blazor) fully C# using WebAssembly and [Xamarin.Forms now supports Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387850/9363973)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/74#issuecomment-373326081) is another great resource on Blazor in an Electron app

Comment: @MindSwipe after doing the step 3 like you mentioned I now get an additional error. See edited question.

Comment: The GTK# installer is for .NET standard, it installs the GTK libraries and registers them in the GAC. I've not tried GTK# with .NET Core 3; it certainly runs on .NET classic for Windows and on Mono across Windows/Mac/Linux. If .NET Core 3 can load the assemblies, I assume they'd need to be in the root of your app? Personally I'm waiting for .NET 5 before porting my GTK# off Mono/.NET 4.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, yet Google likes it.
I have had the similar problem. There are lots of guides that are easy to google but hard to make them work. Here is the [guide](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/wiki/Installing-Gtk-on-Windows) that helped me as of April 2022:

**Step 1: Install MSYS2**
Download the MSYS2 installer and follow the [installation instructions](http://www.msys2.org/).

**Step 2: Install GTK+3** Open a MSYS2 shell, and run: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`

**Step 3: Modify PATH** variable so that the library can be found

```
Open up Control Panel
Go to System and Security > System
Click on the Advanced system settings link
Click on Environment Variables... button
Under System variables find the Path variable and select it
Click the Edit button
Add either ;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin or ;C:\msys32\mingw32\bin to the end of the variable, depending on your system architecture
Click OK, and you are done
Restart your system for the changes to apply
```

To run GtkSharp Samples project you would also need:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtksourceview4`
Otherwise it throws `...System.DllNotFoundException: GtkSource: libgtksourceview-4-0.dll...`

Then you may either install GtkSharp from [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-win) or from nuget.