# Things Like WinForm On Linux - Available?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am a Computer Science student and now my new semester starts and we have to learn vb.net
in windows, WinForm is available but not in Linux
I am Linux User and I Don't Want to shift to Windows.
is there alternative Available For Winform In Linux... I already Searched on Web But it's so confusing

BTW I am Using JB'Rider on My Linux System

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36492583/can-you-develop-linux-applications-with-xamarin

Comment: If winforms is a requirement of your course, you’re probably out of luck.  You might be able to get away with xamarin/mono in some form but winforms pretty much requires windows

Comment: @hursey Winform is not required  I just  want something  like winform mean  drang and drop textbox button and backend with vb

Comment: Pretty sure any drag and drop type designer interface will require winforms.  IMO you’re just going to end up making things harder for yourself

Comment: @Hursey Basically  Ur Say That There Is not Other alternative  of winform

Comment: Btw What about  WPF

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/) or [Uno platform](https://platform.uno/). Both WPF or WinForms won't work since they are not cross platform and they have many Windows (GDI, DirectX...) dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of the class you won't find anything close enough that will satisfy your assignment requirements. If your professor will be testing/grading in Windows, your program needs to run there, too.

What you can do is do your development work in a Virtual Machine, where you can run Windows as a guest in your existing environment. Microsoft also provides **Labs** that may provide you access to a suitable VM over the web.